# Leaderboard-Class instead of KO in Roblox

Tags: roblox

i'm creating a game at the moment and i need to know to add a section into the leaderboard like how the KO system works, however i need it to display names of the classes, such as "Wizard" etc. Making them into teams instead makes it too crowded and this would help.

Comment: The most common way to do it would be basically the same way as the KO system but instead of an **Integer** the value is a **String.** When a play changes class you just need to change their leaderboard value like you would for KO's.

Answer (score 1):

You can add multiple types of values to your leaderboard (`leaderstats`) object by putting different value objects.  For example, if you want to have titles on the leaderboard, you put a `StringValue` into your `leaderstats` object.

## Code:

```lua
local players = game:GetService("Players")

function playerAdded(player)
    local leaderstats = Instance.new("Folder")
    leaderstats.Parent = player
    leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"

    local title = Instance.new("StringValue")
    title.Parent = leaderstats
    title.Name = "Class"
    title.Value = "Wizard" -- or whatever you want it to be
end

players.PlayerAdded:Connect(playerAdded)
```

To change the class, all you have to do is change the value of the StringValue `Class`.

```
player.leaderstats.Class.Value = "Warrior"
```

## References:

https://www.robloxdev.com/articles/Leaderboards

https://www.robloxdev.com/api-reference/event/Players/PlayerAdded

https://www.robloxdev.com/api-reference/class/StringValue